# How to redirect to the same page after social login using django allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

i tried using the next parameter but it doesnt affect anything

here is the template

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" next='{{ request.path }}'%} "><img src = "{% static 'images/fbconnect.png' %}" height="45px" ></a>
                     <a href="{% provider_login_url "google" method="connect" next='{{ request.path }}'%} "><img src = "{% static 'images/g_login.png' %}" height="45px" ></a>
                  </div>
```

here is the view

```
if request.POST.get('action') == 'login':
                username_email = request.POST.get('user_email')
                password = request.POST.get('password')
                try:
                    the_user = User.objects.get(username=username_email)
                except:
                    the_user = User.objects.get(email=username_email)

                if the_user is not None:
                    user = authenticate(username=username_email , password=password)
                    if user is not None:
                        login(request , user)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status' : 'True'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect param doesn't work in you example because you are not using it in your view, you are just returning HttpResponse.

You should return HttpResponseRedirect with URL where you want to redirect your user. Please see how allauth implements this here:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py

Specifically, see these two lines in RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, where redirect URL is fetched and redirected:

```
redirect_to = self.get_authenticated_redirect_url()
response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```